# Error with \addtosubstitutions from chickenize package

Tags: errors, luatex, chickenize

The command `\addtosubstitutions{word1}{word2}` is defined by the `chickenize` package to replace  each occurence of `word1` with `word2`. If `word1` is `a` an error will result

```
! Undefined control sequence \relAx
```

Minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chickenize}

\begin{document}

\addtosubstitutions{a}{A}

\substitutewords

text

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error message shows you the problem:

```
 (./test-utf8.aux
! Undefined control sequence.
l.1 \relABx
         
? x
```

You can see that the aux-file has been opened at the end of the document, and then the `a` in the `\relax` is replaced by `AB` and gives an unknown control sequence.

That command names are affected too is explicitly mentioned in the documentation. So be careful and deactivate the command if needed:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chickenize}

\begin{document}

\addtosubstitutions{a}{AB} 

\substitutewords

text

\unsubstitutewords

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there a way to substitute words without affecting commands in luatex?

Comment: well it is not trivial. How do you know if "frame" and "quote" is a word or for example the name of an environment and so part of a command?

Comment: chicknise use `process_input_buffer` callback for  `\substitutewords` command, Is there a possibility that another callback can produce the desired effect?